# Dynamic Programming - String, Substrings and Minimum Cost

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming, computer-science

Dear Computer Science experts,

I have a question regarding Dynamic Programming (DP). The problem is I am given a sentence of characters and a cost_list that contains a list of substrings of sentence with their costs, the goal is to find lowest cost. It is assumed that cost_list contains all the substrings in sentence.

For example, suppose I have the below parameters,

**sentence** = "xxxyyzz"

**cost_list** = [["x", 1], ["xx", 3], ["y", 3], ["yy", 1], ["z", 2]]

So **sentence** could be [xx][x][yy][z][z], so the total cost is 3 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 9

But I could also select the substrings in sentence in a different way and we have [x][x][x][yy][z][z], which gives us 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 8 and it is the lowest cost.

The question is to construct a Dynamic Programming algorithm **find_lowest_cost(sentence, cost_list)**.

Below is my recursive function for this problem I created, I have tested and it is correct,

```
def find_lowest_cost(sentence, cost_list):
   if len(sentence) == 0:
       return 0
   else:
       result = []
       possible_substrings = []
       possible_costs = []
       for c in cost_list:
           current_substring = c[0]
           current_cost = c[1]

           if current_substring == sentence[0:len(current_substring)]:
               possible_substrings.append(current_substring)
               possible_costs.append(current_cost)

       for i in range(0, len(possible_substrings)):
           result.append(possible_costs[i] + find_lowest_cost(sentence[len(possible_substrings[i]):], cost_list))

       return min(result)


sentence = "xxxyyzz"
cost_list = [["x", 1], ["xx", 3], ["y", 3], ["yy", 1], ["z", 2]]
print(find_lowest_cost(sentence, cost_list))
```

I am stuck on how to converting the Recursion to Dynamic Programming (DP).

Question 1: For DP table, my columns are the characters of **sentence**. How what should my rows be? My thinking is it can't be a rows of "x", "xx", "y", "yy" and "z" because how would we compare "yy" with, say only "y" in **sentence**?

Question 2: Suppose rows and columns are figured out, at the current cell, what should the current cell be built upon? My notion is the cell is built-upon the lowest value of previous cells, such as cell[row][col-1], cell[row-1][col] and cell[row-1][col-1]?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to address a single question, show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hi, I just need help on my two questions that I have difficulty with. I did mention my thinking and need if my logic is correct.

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: My biggest problem is all other DP questions are 1-1 comparison, 1 character compared with another character, but the problem I'm facing is multiple in-order characters comparison, why I am not familiar with. I will modify my question in an hour as I am still in process of getting the DP table from Recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to solve the DP table. My guess is this one also requires me to do the 3D DP table thing, which I am not familiar with. This is what I dislike about Computer Science at my school, which is top 20 best university in the world, Profs teach easy questions that can be found online but the homework problems are multiply difficult.

Comment: Since at it's essence DP is an algorithmic approach whereby you break the problem down into sub problems and then solve each sub problem recursively, You might think about breaking the string down into substrings containing sequences of like characters and solving these substrings recursively

Answer (score 0):

Once you are able to get the recursive solution then try to look for how many variable are getting changed. Analysing the recursive approach:

> We need to find a solution like, what is the minimum cost when string is having length 1, then 2 so on... There would be repetitive calculation for substring from 0 to k th index so we need to store all calculated result into single dp so that we can give the answer of any k th index which has already calculated.
> Below is my Java solution.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MyClass {
    private static Integer[] dp;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // cost_list = [["x", 1], ["xx", 3], ["y", 3], ["yy", 1], ["z", 2]]
        HashMap<String, Integer> costmp = new HashMap();
        costmp.put("x", 1);
        costmp.put("xx", 3);
        costmp.put("y", 3);
        costmp.put("yy", 1);
        costmp.put("z", 2);
        
        String sentence = "xxxyyzz";
        // String sentence = "xxyyzzxxxxyyyyxxxyxxyyyxxyyyzzzyyyxxxyyyyzzzyyyyxxxyyyzzzyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyxyxyzzzzxxyyxx";
        // String sentence = "xxxyyzzxxxxyyyyxxxyxxyyyxxyyyzzzyyyxxxyyyyzzzy";
        dp = new Integer[sentence.length()+1];
        int res = find_lowest_cost(sentence, costmp, 0);
      System.out.println("find_lowest_cost = " + res);
    }


    private static int find_lowest_cost(String sentence, HashMap<String, Integer> costmp, int st)
    {
        if(st == sentence.length())
            return 0;
        int mincost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(dp[st] != null)
            return dp[st];
        String str = new String();
        for(int i = st;i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            str+=sentence.charAt(i);
            if(!costmp.containsKey(str))
                break;
            int cost = costmp.get(str);
            mincost = Math.min(mincost, cost+find_lowest_cost(sentence, costmp, i+1));
        }
        dp[st] = mincost;
        return mincost;
    }
}
```